# OLS prediction plot conditional on covariates

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am fitting a linear model `mpg ~ disp + vs + wt`

this is my output.

```
model1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + vs + wt, data = mtcars)
summary(model1)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + vs + wt, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-3.701 -2.413 -0.105  1.471  5.953 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 32.82909    2.39738   13.69  6.2e-14 ***
disp        -0.00669    0.01077   -0.62   0.5395    
vs           2.63718    1.46349    1.80   0.0823 .  
wt          -3.83847    1.15368   -3.33   0.0025 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.81 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.804, Adjusted R-squared:  0.783 
F-statistic: 38.2 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 4.94e-10
```

How can I create a plot of
-predicted value plot( pred(mpg(y)) ~ disp(x) where **vs =0**,  **wt = average of wt** )
-predicted value plot( pred(mpg(y)) ~ disp(x) where **vs =0**,  **wt = 10th percentile of wt**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to predict the trends of interest in a seperate dataframe and use these as the data argument for seperate geoms.

```r
library(ggplot2)

fit <- lm(mpg ~ disp + vs + wt, data = mtcars)

trend1 <- data.frame(
  disp = seq(min(mtcars$disp), max(mtcars$disp), length.out = 200),
  vs = 0, wt = mean(mtcars$wt)
)

trend1$mpg <- predict(fit, newdata = trend1)

trend2 <- data.frame(
  disp = seq(min(mtcars$disp), max(mtcars$disp), length.out = 200),
  vs = 0, wt = unname(quantile(mtcars$wt, 0.1))
)
trend2$mpg <- predict(fit, newdata = trend2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = trend1, aes(colour = "average wt")) +
  geom_line(data = trend2, aes(colour = "10th percentile wt"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @teubrand, interesting teunbrand, i will study this a bit more. Thanks.